# Counting number of words on each page in Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm attempting to write a macro in Word that inserts a marker at the beginning of each page in tiny font so it doesn't bump any text forward to the next page. (I then output the document to HTML and do some additional processing of the markers there in Javascript.)

I have basically figured out the script to do that:

```
Sub Test()


    Dim PageCounter As Long
    Dim FirstPageInput As String
    Dim PageFirstWordRange As Range
    Dim InsertWord As String
   
    FirstPageInput = InputBox("What is the initial page number for this article?", "First Page Number?")
   
   
    For PageCounter = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")

        Set PageFirstWordRange = ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, PageCounter)
       
        'If this is the first page, add the initial page number. Otherwise, just insert a marker.'
        If PageCounter = 1 Then
            InsertWord = "!@" + FirstPageInput + "@! "
            PageFirstWordRange.InsertBefore (InsertWord)
        Else
            'PageFirstWordRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1'
            InsertWord = " !@@! "
            PageFirstWordRange.InsertAfter (InsertWord)
        End If
       
        'Select the word we just inserted, and change its size to 1'
        With PageFirstWordRange.Font
            .Size = 1
        End With
       
    Next
End Sub
```

The issue is that there are sometimes pages and pages filled up with footnotes. Because the script tries to find the first word on each page, it ends up skipping these footnote pages (not writing a marker for them) and I need the script to do that.

The solution I've decided is to count the words on each page as I iterate. If there are any pages with 0 text (not including the footnotes) then I will add an additional marker for each blank page.

I have no idea how to do this - I'm so bad with VBA. Does anyone have a solution for me? This feels like an easy thing to do, but I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: Are the footnotes meant to be counted? And what about content in textboxes, etc.?

Comment: See also Word Does Not Know What a Page Is by Word MVP Daiya Mitchell. https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html Although written a while back, it is still valid. You will end up with arbitrary pages. Footnotes, text boxes and headers and footers are in different stories than is the main document. *That is, to Word they are not on the page.* You might try saving as pdf and then opening the pdf in Word. (I have not tried this.)

Comment: @macropod - No - footnotes, textboxes, etc. should not be counted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Thanks for the interesting link. I could sense that Word doesn't have an easy "page containing lines of text" model you might expect when first encountering their API, but this explains far more clearly why that is. I'm still hoping for some way to hack this, though!

Comment: If you have pages that consist of nothing other than footnotes or endnotes, there is no body content on those pages to count. So it's hardly surprising those pages get skipped. On wonders why you'd have a multi-page footnote - it seems to me that content that extensive should be in the document body. To work around the blank pages issue, you would have to split the footnote so that it doesn't occupy a full page, thus allowing some body content to appear there. That, of course, would compromise your document's integrity.